# Namecheap vps and godaddy domain connect

Tags: vpn, hosts, godaddy

Hello I have Domain on Godaddy, I want to connect with new hosting on Namecheap but i can't find the NS of namecheap server.

Someone to help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I use Namecheap’s shared hosting, but this may work too with vps

```
dns1.namecheaphosting.com
dns2.namecheaphosting.com
```